# Remove strings that contain two or more capital letters from a vector in r

Tags: r

I have the following vector for an example.

```
isotopes <- c("6Li", "7Li", "7LiH", "10B", "11B", "11BH")
```

I want to remove the strings `"7LiH"` and `"11BH"` from the vector. These values have two capital letters and so I am trying to figure out how to use `grep` to remove those values or just index out the other strings in the vector. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply grep for elements that contain 2 or more capital letters and invert the match:

```
grep('[A-Z].*[A-Z]', isotopes, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
```

The regex matches a string that contains an uppercase letter, then probably something else and then one more uppercase letter (not necessary at the beginning or end)

Answer (score 3):

I made a slight modification to the code so that it could match any digit or lowercase letter between 2 uppercase:

```
isotopes[!grepl('[A-Z]([1-9a-z]+)?[A-Z]', isotopes)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to count the number of uppercase letters using `stringr`, then keep only the strings that have less than 2 uppercase letters.

```
library(stringr)

isotopes[str_count(isotopes, "[A-Z]") < 2]

# "6Li" "7Li" "10B" "11B"
```

Or with `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)

isotopes[stri_count(isotopes, regex="[A-Z]") < 2]
```

Or with base R:

```
isotopes[lengths(gregexpr("[A-Z]", isotopes)) < 2]
```